# With Highmaps, why is the callback in my jQuery fadein happening prior to the fade completing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, fadeout, highmaps

I have a HighMap with a pair of buttons that are used to change between datasets - this is working as intended. I wanted to add a fade so that the switch between the datasets is smooth. However the map seems to be updating the data prior to the fadeout completing, despite happening within the callback function of the fade.

Here's the relevant bit of code with the buttons:

```
var resetMap = function(dataCurrent) {
SetOptions(dataCurrent);
AccessMap.update({title: {text: dataTitle}});
AccessMap.update({colorAxis: {max: dataMax, min: dataMin, minColor: dataMinColor, maxColor: dataMaxColor,type: dataScale}});
AccessMap.update({series:[{name: dataTitle,tooltip:{ valueSuffix: dataTooltipSuffix}}]});
AccessMap.series[0].setData(dataCurrent.slice());
};

$('#setdataPop').click(function() {
$("#container").fadeOut(500,resetMap(pop));
$("#container").fadeIn(500);
});

$('#setdataRate').click(function() {
$("#container").fadeOut(500,resetMap(rate16));
$("#container").fadeIn();
});
```

A simplified version of my full working map (which includes the setOptions function referenced in that snippet) is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/MossTheTree/h5njdqLf/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing `resetMap` in place, not passing a function reference. You also probably want to run the `fadeIn` inside the callback as well:

```
$("#container").fadeOut(500, function() {
    resetMap(pop);
    $("#container").fadeIn(500);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm going to have to read more to fully understand the difference - it appears that I have to define a function in the callback, rather than call one directly.

Comment: You should not call it directly since you don't want the side-effects of that function to happen immediately. Animations are asynchronous by nature, that means they end sometime in the future. jQuery lets you define what happens once an animation has finished. Hence why you want to give the reference to your function to jQuery, so it can call it when the animation has finished, rather than yourself invoking it immediately.

Comment: Also, what made it easier for me is to think about functions in terms of their effects. Whenever a label ends with `()` that means you're invoking it immediately. If you substitute that whole bit with the function result (or its effects), would you want that to happen right there and then, or not?

Comment: Last note, you don't have to define the function in the callback. Having a function defined beforehand and just passing its name (reference) also works: `var onReset = function() { resetMap(pop) }; $("#container").fadeOut(500, onReset);` - notice the absence of `()` which would invoke the function immediately.

Comment: This is all extremely useful, not just for this question but for my learning overall. Thanks so much!

Comment: No worries! Hope that cleared it up for you. Happy coding!